# Как передать массив и другие переменные в другой класс?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Как передать массивы/переменные в другой класс, что бы там можно было их использовать?

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfPassword;
    sqlite3 *passwordDB;
    NSString *dbPathString;

}
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)createOrOpenDB
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"password.db"];

    char *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString])
    {
        const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &passwordDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PASSWORD (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, WEB_SITES TEXT, LOGIN TEXT, E_MAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, URL TEXT)";
            sqlite3_exec(passwordDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(passwordDB);
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Вот масив и переменная:

```
NSString *dbPathString;
NSAarray *arrayOfPassword;
```

Мне нужно их использовать в другом классе

Comment: Hint: у методов бывают аргументы.

Comment: @VladD, І шо мені з ними робить треба, шоб воно запрацювало?

Comment: @leonid, будьте добры изъясняться на русском языке, тут не все понимают украинский

Comment: Уточните, Вы работаете со сторибордами или с ксибами для формирования интерфейса?

Comment: @leonid3452: телепати у вiдпустцi, а что вам надо сделать? Давайте код.

Comment: Я работаю со сторибордами, у меня в одном классе есть массив и переменные, и мне нужно их использовать в другом классе

Comment: При инициализации контроллера, прежде чем на него уйдет пользователь, в него можно передать необходимые дынные. Для этого в контроллере, в который требуется передать данные нужно создать @property соотвествующее.

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Передайте в другой класс ваш instance `ViewController`, сделайте getter'ы для `dbPathString` и `arrayOfPassword`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашёл иной способ, наследовался от первого класса, и во втором юзал его все переменные.

Comment: Один UIViewController наследует от другого UIViewControllr'а? Это по крайней мере не верное решение!

Comment: @zhenyab, Наследовал класс один от другого, почему не правильное?
Всё что мне нужно было, так это класс - в котором было подключение к БД, что бы в классе где именно кнопки/методы таблицы и т.д не было кода с подключением БД, он мне просто мешал, глаза выедал, я его перенёс, и наследовал :)

А почему не верное, обьясните пожалуйста :)

Comment: Если Вы вынесли весь код, который ответственный за управление базой данных в отдельный класс и вызываете его в каждом UIViewController, то все верно, но если UIViewController наследует от другого UIViewController, то с этим могут возникнуть проблемы, потому что каждый UIView имеет только один UIViewController с которым он и разговаривает. А когда идет наследование, то смешиваются методы, переменные и т.п. Может начаться полная неразбериха.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, я бы настоятельно рекомендовал бы почитать книгу по азам программирования в Objective-C и iOS framework в частности.

Дальше я предлагаю код, который позволит Вам на данном этапе сделать то, что Вы хотите:

```
@interface TargetViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dbPathString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayOfPassword;

@end
```

@property (nonatomic, strong) - вот это директива динамически создает геттеры и сеттеры, которые могут быть публично доступны и видимы для всех снаружи.

Теперь нам осталось инициализировать контроллер, и передать в сеттеры соответствующие данные из ViewController, прежде чем отправить пользователя на другой View:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"segueID"]) {

        TargetViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [tvc setDbPathString: dbPathString];
        [tvc setArrayOfPassword: arrayOfPassword];

    }
}
```

Я исходил из того, что Вы работаете со Storyboard и отправляете пользователя используя segue.

Comment: Я бы не давал setter'ы, как-то это неправильно. Если чужому классу надо подсмотреть свойства, getter'ов должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Чтобы не давать сеттеров это ж нужно с другого конца идти. Обращаться к ViewController из TargetViewController и делать делегирование, а для данного уровня - этого вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще такие вещи решаются через [делегирование](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9) как тут уже советовали. Cториборды позволяют скрыть этот процесс и несколько упростить в коде.
Ваши шаги:

1) В вашем втором классе создаете проперти для массива и переменной соответствующих типов (NSArray и NSString) и сделайте `#import` второго класса

2)  В первом классе (из которого будете передавать) делаете переменные которые хотите передать глобальными для данного класса

3) Кнопке в сториборде которая будет инициировать переход задаете тэг (например - 100)

3) В первом классе переопределяете метод `-prepareForSegue:sender:` так

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
         if (sender.tag == 100) //  проверка та ли кнопка нажата
         {
                SecondViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController]; // получение ссылки на второй класс
                svc.array = [NSArray initWithArray: arrayOfPassword]; // инициализация массива во втором классе вашим изначальным массивом
                svc.string = [NSString initWithString:dbPathString];
         }
 }
```

Comment: И соглашусь с @zhenyab, Вам очень нужно почитать про основы программирования и основы работы с iOS, без этого никак

Comment: @AlexThumb, можете подсказать толковые ссылки/книги, где всё разжевано для самых маленьких?

Comment: @leonid3452 - английским владеете?

Comment: objc очень хорошо подан в книге Стивена Кочана, это хороший учебник для новичков в программировании вообще и справочник материалов по языку. Концепцию делегирования смотрите по ссылке которую я привел в ответе или бейте в гугл

Answer (score 0):

на Hexlet.org есть даже подробный урок, как работать с сеттерами и геттерами